# Symfony - Guzzle request: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host

Tags: php, symfony, curl, nginx, guzzle

I have a symfony application with two controllers. One of the controllers randomly return an element of an array, like this:

```
$responses = array("foo", "bar", "baz");

return new JsonResponse($responses[array_rand($responses)]);
```

The other one has a form and if that form is valid and is submitted it should create a new guzzle client and display one of the array elements from the other controller:

```
...
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'foo.local',
    ]);
    $response = $client->request('GET', '/bar');
```

This results in  a **cURL error 6: Could not resolve host.**

I do have nginx up and running and can access both controllers separately via their routes.

I could not find any solutions, hope someone can help me out with some ideas on this.

Comment: have you tried with the protocol? something like `'base_uri' => 'http://foo.local',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using protocol in the base uri solves the could not resolve host error

`'base_uri' => 'http://foo.local'` instead of `'base_uri' => 'foo.local'` in this case

Thans for the help @Matteo

Comment: you are welcome! Mark the answer as accepted so you can close the question